# iOS socket list of hosts wlan

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets, wifi

I have some WLAN-Device, that I communicate with. 
At first I go to IOS Settings and connect to the device directly. 
Then in my App I need to input the ip and port to open a socket. 
Until now I knew the IP and Port, to open a socket connection to this device. 
But if I am already connected (Adhoc) to the device, why I can not find this stuff automatically? 
I already saw some solutions, but most of them need the usage of dynamic libs or just not longer available in iOS7.1. I can not use dynamic libs, because this App should go to AppStore.

Comment: can you please give more detail about the question?

Comment: Over the Setting you you connect to some WLAN Device. From that point it should be possible to knew what ip and port the opponent has. But to open a socket I used a port and IP of the device: CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef) ip, port, &readStream, &writeStream); Now I would like to find out, what ip und port the opponent has before I open a socket.

Comment: For that you have to ping to the all the ip address range, but pinging is not much easy task in iOS to do. Can't you manually enter the ip address of your devices?

Comment: I already do, but the point is, that different devices can be configured with different IP and Port configs. So I am looking for the easy way to find this stuff out.

Comment: If your both devices are in the same WLAN, both of them should be in the same range. Eg : if one device's ip address is 192.168.16.3, other device's ip address should be in 192.168.16.x range. you should read about TCP/IP for that. I'm not sure about the range exactly.

Comment: Ok, why not. If I get my own IP, I could ping the other 253 addresses to check for devices. But how about port? My port is 30000 and I would not like to scan for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no other way since iOS 6. 
You have to scan the location. "Reachability" could help you, if you know the name of the host. Also you could try to scan the posible IP's. With Thread limited by 5 Operations it could go preaty fast.